# DeQueueAny function not working as it's supposed to

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

So the prompt for this question is a popular one. It is as follows:

An animal shelter holds only dogs and cats, and operates on a strictly "first in, first out" basis. People must adopt either the "oldest" (based on arrival time) of all animals at the shelter, or they can select whether they would prefer a dog or a cat (and will receive the oldest animal of that type). They cannot select which specific animal they would like. Create the data structures to maintain this system and implement operations such as enqueue, dequeueAny, dequeueDog and dequeueCat.

For some reason, my dequeue any isn't working, specifically where I am comparing the date of the animal in the cat queue compared to the one in the dog queue. It only works when I start with adding a dog first in my array list but doesn't work when I add a cat first...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnimalShelter as = new AnimalShelter();
        List<Animal> animals = Arrays.asList(new Cat(),new Dog(),new Cat(),new Dog(),new Cat(),
        new Dog(),new Cat(),new Dog(),new Cat());

        for (Animal animal : animals) {
            as.enqueue(animal);
        }
        
        System.out.println(as.cats.peek().dateArrived.compareTo(as.dogs.peek().dateArrived));
        as.dequeueAny();
        System.out.println(as.cats.size());
        System.out.println(as.dogs.size());
    }

public Animal dequeueAny() throws Exception {
            boolean noCat = cats.isEmpty();
            boolean noDog = dogs.isEmpty();
            if (noCat && noDog)
                throw new Exception("There are no more animals!");
            if (noCat)
                return dogs.poll();
            else if (noDog)
                return cats.poll();
            else
                return cats.peek().dateArrived.compareTo(dogs.peek().dateArrived) < 0 ? cats.poll(): dogs.poll();`
        }
```

For some reason the peek().compareTo() returns 0.

Comment: It thinks the date is the same